# Unknown monitor replacement cable

Tags: display, cable, repair

I am trying to repair a LG W2452V monitor that I had lying around. It seems I am missing the cable going from the main board to the headphone-jack/control buttons boards. The connectors look like the one in the picture: they have 11 pins each and are both male. Does anyone have any idea what the name for this kind of cable is?

P.S. I have been searching for a name for the past 2 hours and I hope it's not something obvious.
[image: connector image]

Comment: That's a single-row IDC connector. The cable you need is probably something like [this one](http://donnex.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008800044599/pdtl/Crimp-connector/1008920173/Wire-to-Board-Crimp-Connector-and-Single-Row-IDC-Socket.htm).

Comment: Thank you. You are propably right. I will check it out. If you make an answer out of your comment, i can pick it as the correct one and mark my question as answered.